# Tabular Editor in Power BI Does not Sync in Power BI Itself and Vice Versa

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Measures edited in Tabular Editor and saved are not syncing with Power BI and vice versa. So when I make a change in 1, I have to physically copy to the other.

Any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tabular editor 2.16.1 and whenever measures are created in bulk there, it does not autosave back to the model as there is no auto sync.

You need to manually save them back to the model either by pressing the highlighted button
[image: Tabular editor]

Or by pressing `Ctrl+S`